# Can i move "overflow hidden" box without moving of contents?

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

I just tried to hide parts of the contents with a box.

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contents {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div class="contents">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem blanditiis, tempora corporis est vero doloribus quos odit mollitia fugiat dolorem? Accusamus, maiores. Temporibus quidem quia dignissimos repellat inventore aperiam perspiciatis!asd</div>

</div>
```

My question : 
Is it possible that I move only the box position and fix the contents at the same position?

[image]

Comment: You want to able to scroll and have the box move down and reveal the remaining content?

Comment: I added a example picture that i want as final. sorry about poor english. i just wanted to have margin 30px or top and left 30px. Therefore box will have distance from the edge of window . but i want to fix the text contents like in the picture

Answer (score 0):

You have to style the text in order to achieve your goal, try this:
If you add a wrapper-div, you could use the `.wrapper` to set the width, height and position of the whole object. With the child div `.box` you can define the width, height and position of your coloured background (yellow in your example) and with the final nested div `.contents` you can then define the width and height of your text within the box.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color:gray;
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
}

.box{
  position:relative;
  left: 30px;
  top:30px;
  
  background-color:yellow;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  
  overflow:hidden;
}

.contents{
  width:50px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  word-wrap: break-word ;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="contents">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem blanditiis, tempora corporis est vero doloribus quos odit mollitia fugiat dolorem? Accusamus, maiores. Temporibus quidem quia dignissimos repellat inventore aperiam perspiciatis!asd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```